# How to Create an Excel Macro to Display Special Character Code

Tags: excel, unicode, vba

It would be really handy to have a little Excel macro that could look up a the character code of a unicode special character. Something like.

```
dim x As String
x = ActiveCell.Value
Something that would convert x from ChrW(code) to code
MsgBox x
```

We can assume that the character will be alone in the ActiveCell. Any thoughts on how to do this?

Answer (score 0):

Here you go:

```
msgbox AscW(activecell.Value)
```